# routing class based tasks in celery based on class inheritance

Tags: python, routes, celery

Suppose I have the following celery tasks defined as classes

```
from celery import Task

class BaseTask(Task):
    abstract = True 

    def run():
        pass  # not important

class SpecificTask(BaseTask):
    def run():
        pass # not important
```

Is there an easy way to set routing for all taks inheriting from BaseTaks class? Ideally I would like to do something like:

```
CELERY_ROUTES = {
    'project.tasks.BaseTask': {'queue': 'notify'},
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work as I intended.

Thanks for advice.

Comment: Setting BaseTask.queue='notify' is a way I know about. However I would rather keep these things in config file.